# Reachability Notification Never Called

Tags: objective-c, ios, app-store, appstore-approval, reachability

I am having a hard time using Reachability in my code. I would like to keep it very simple by initiating an observer at launch and then just receiving change notifications. In the following code, the reachabilityChanged method is never called. I’ve tried many iterations but this is the simplest version. It compiles and runs. Please help...

****** AppDelegate.h code ************

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#ifdef PHONEGAP_FRAMEWORK
    #import <PhoneGap/PGViewController.h>
    #import <PhoneGap/PGURLProtocol.h>
    #import <PhoneGap/Reachability.h>
#else
    #import "PGViewController.h"
    #import "PGURLProtocol.h"
    #import "Reachability.h"

#endif

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject < UIApplicationDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate, PGCommandDelegate> {
    NSString* invokeString;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy)  NSString* invokeString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWindow* window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet PGViewController* viewController;

@end
```

****** AppDelegate.m code snippet ************

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "MainViewController.h"

#ifdef PHONEGAP_FRAMEWORK
    #import <PhoneGap/PGPlugin.h>
    #import <PhoneGap/PGURLProtocol.h>
    #import <PhoneGap/Reachability.h>
#else
    #import "PGPlugin.h"
    #import "PGURLProtocol.h"
    #import "Reachability.h"

#endif

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize invokeString, window, viewController;

- (void) reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)notice
{

    NSLog(@"???????? CODE NEVER GETS HERE ??????????");

    Reachability *reach = [notice object];
    NSParameterAssert([reach isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]]);
    NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];

    if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable) {NSLog(@"**** Not Reachable ****");}
    else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFi) {NSLog(@"**** wifi ****"); }
    else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWWAN) {NSLog(@"**** cell ****"); }
}

- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{    

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [reach startNotifier];

    NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];

    NSLog(@”???? ALWAYS INITS WITH Not Reachable ????”);
    if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable) {NSLog(@"init **** Not Reachable ****");}
    else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFi) {NSLog(@"int **** wifi ****"); }
    else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWWAN) {NSLog(@"init **** cell ****"); }

    // ...

}

@end
```

Comment: Surely the title and/or tags can be updated to make this question easier to identify...

Comment: Just edited - hopefully title and tags are more descriptive.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your object Reachability is autorelease so it's dealloc and not working anymore.

I try your code and it's working for me:

**AppDelegate.h code**

```
[...]
@property (retain, nonatomic)  Reachability* reach;
[...]
```

**AppDelegate.m code snippet**

```
[...]
@synthesize reach;

- (void) reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)notice
{

    NSLog(@"!!!!!!!!!! CODE IS CALL NOW !!!!!!!!!!");

    NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];

    if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable) {NSLog(@"**** Not Reachable ****");}
    else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFi) {NSLog(@"**** wifi ****"); }
    else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWWAN) {NSLog(@"**** cell ****"); }
}

- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{    

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

    self.reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]; //retain reach
    [reach startNotifier];

    NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];

    NSLog(@"???? ALWAYS INITS WITH Not Reachable ????");
    if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable) {NSLog(@"init **** Not Reachable ****");}
    else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFi) {NSLog(@"int **** wifi ****"); }
    else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWWAN) {NSLog(@"init **** cell ****"); }

    // ...

}

[...]
-(void)dealloc{
    [reach release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: I think that's it! I tried your modifications by turning Airplane Mode on and I see the proper log messages. Thank you so, so much!

Comment: @Sarah Moreland You're welcome. As you are a new user I take the freedom to remind you to vote up for my reply if you like it and/or accept the reply if it solved your problem. The button are on the top left of my answer

Comment: Thanks, I checked the accept answer but am unable to up vote because I don't have a 15 reputation. I would if I could. It's a great answer.