# Depends on internet Connection show a ViewController iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I'm making an application with storyboards, the first VC, is a navigationController and automatically shows the next VC that it´s just a login , once the user is logged, is send to a TabBarcontroller with 3 items in which I already have a validation of the connection to do certain things when there is internet and others when not, now my question is how to validate if there is internet go to the login VC, if no internet, jump directly to the TabBarcontroller?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apple's Reachability class to check for a network connection.

1) Add the SystemConfiguration.framework to your project.

2) Download Apple's Reachability class from http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

3) In your code `#import "Reachability.h"` and check for a network connection like this:

```
Reachability *networkReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus networkStatus = [networkReachability currentReachabilityStatus];
if (networkStatus == NotReachable){
// no network connection
} else {
// network connection
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Apple docs for Reachability class** http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

With the above code you can call into the Reachability class to query the current status of the network connection and then decide what to do based on result.

You can also observe the **kReachabilityChangedNotification** so that when a network change occurs your app will take appropriate action.

**here's another tutorial:**
http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/10/18/iphone-app-development-tutorial-check-for-connectivity/

**SO question with some code examples**

[Reachability Notification Never Called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184082/reachability-notification-never-called)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate the internet connection, try [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)