# How can i get a notification if connection status changed?

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, ios7

I am currently working on an app that must check if a user enter his home wifi network in background. (like Geofencing but only run code if user enter or exit his home wifi...)

The problem is, that i don't find a clean solution to do that. Is there a notification that i am missing?

In Android I just programmed this and i have done this with a broadcast receiver, the AndroidOS broadcasts if the network status changed.

Is there something similar in iOS, i don't find something in the Apple Docs.

Thanks

EDIT: 
What is with iOS 7? There is a Background App Refresh Service now.
Is it possible with this, or is this just for downloads?

And what is with local notifications?

Comment: Try this link: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17804830/how-to-get-change-in-network-connection-notification-from-ios-reachability-class

Answer (score 5):

You can give a check to [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability), an iOS class to detect network status changes.
You can register for notifications for events like: no network, wifi connection available, 3g connection available.

A tutorial is available [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-detecting-network-changes-with-reachability/).

Comment: Right, thats what i found too, but the problem is that i have to check the statuschanges in background. If User connect to his HomeWifi i like to run code without bringing the app in foreground again. Any ideas here? A long background task is only 10 minutes. thats not enough is there a infinity background task that wait for the notifications of your posted Reachability class?

Comment: Ok, so the issue is not really how to detect a network status change. Unfortunately, unless your app falls into one of a finite set of cases, you do not have any chance to do that. Check here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3 , under "Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks". Do not know if you can "bend" one of those cases to your requirements.