# Automatically detect if my mobile is connected to Internet

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
-(BOOL)IsConnectionAvailable{
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];   
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    return !(networkStatus == NotReachable);
}
```

I am using above code and have to call that periodically to check if there is network connection.
I am working on chat application where i want to send messages immediately one the device get connected to network.

Thanks

Comment: refer this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17804830/how-to-get-change-in-network-connection-notification-from-ios-reachability-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **kReachabilityChangedNotification**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkForReachability:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

}

- (void) checkForReachability:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if([self IsConnectionAvailable])// use your method here
    {
        // net available
    }
    else
    {
        // no internet
    }

}
```